# Is it good practice to use property text placeholders inside JSPs?

Tags: java, html, jsp, jsf, spring-webflow

For many projects I have worked on, programming teams work with the style of placholding every piece of static text in an xhtml file into a properties file. For example:

xhtml=

> ```
> ...
> <h1>${messages.resourceBundle['key.to.static.text.placeholder']}</h1>
> ...
> ```

messages.properties=

> ```
> ...
> key.to.static.text.placeholder=This will be the heading for this page only
> ...
> ```

Would anybody be able to explain what the advantage in this is?

So far, I can only see the following disadvantages:

- making changes to any xhtml file requires you to hunt for the correct .properties file, and then the individual property to make the change to
- if others have re-used properties, then deleting them becomes tricky as you have to be certain no other page is referencing the property, therefore after several change request rounds, properties files become large with redundant properties
- if there are 1000 xhtmls, there will be 1000 .properties files to load, which is more   cycles on the cpu to load and inject static pieces of text
- if your using WebFlow and have flows that pass into other flows, properties have to be duplicated, meaning that sometimes you must place the same property in many different properties files to render correctly
- hard to read code; if you know you want to work on the text 'This will be the heading for this page' only, you'll need to work out where that is on the xhtml from the property files first - you can't simply look at the xhtml and see clearly how the content will be laid out once rendered.

The only advantages I can see are text reuse and possibly html escaping.

Apologies if its coding 101, but I've had a hunt around Google and can't find the reasoning to the pattern.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common practice for internationalizing content. 
You create one property file per language (or locale) and use a dynamic way off resolving which one to load depending on the context. (e.g. Language HTTP header the browser sends).

It is arguably more flexible than providing 1 jsp file per language, and can still deal with complex cases where plurals or stylistic differences might change the way you write localized text.

This is a standard JDK feature, lookup resource bundles. 
You do not have to build 1 file per jsp (maybe your framework works this way?), although doing so can help the person writing the translation.